# Need to Open file in Read-only in SharePoint Online

Tags: read-only

By default, SharePoint Online files are opening in Online mode (Edit form), but my requirement is to open SharePoint file in Read-only mode by default in the browser (Chrome & Edge) then it will ask me to Choose Edit options.

Please share your suggestions

Thanks 
Sai

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue before. What I had figured out, it happened after I synced my SharePoint library with the onedrive client in my PC. To solve the problem, I un-sync the library by unticking it from the settings.

Comment: In my case, we haven't synced locally because we have huge data in SharePoint

Answer (score 0):

you can't change that behavior from my experience, but if the docs are in the old format of doc for example for word it will open in read only and documents in new formats docx will open in edit mode.

that being said I'm not sure what exactly are your requirements but if the library is set to have the users check out a document before editing it you can click View in Browser and it will open in read only mode until you check out and edit.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use permission to target the view.  Click the file and select "Manage". Then select all site visitors with "view" permission. Note that site owners/editors will launch in Edit instead of "view" mode. But, this is desired mode for contributors.